# How to autofill table column in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to develop a simple database that stores taking information for a taxi daily figure etc. and there are some calculations that I would like to have auto-filled from basic information supplied by the driver, such as:

- gross takings given a start and end value from a metering device km's
- driven given an odometer reading driver owner split given the days takings

The problem I have is I would like to store all these values in a single attribute to make retrieval and entry into another third party system easier. Currently this is paper based and I am trying to digitize this process

The operations are simple mathematical expressions such as addition subtraction and percentage split (multiplication or division)

I've tried various sql commands like

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldname)
   select 
      table.feildname1, table.feildname2, [feildname2]-[fieldname1]
   from 
      table
```

I will be using a input form for data entry that will display the basic data input and a drivers share of takings/expenses based upon these calculations

And I'm drawing a blank I'm using ms access 2007

Comment: "i would like to store all these values in a single attribute" -> Do not store combined fields in your database. You can easily combine them upon retrieval. You could also calculate during retrieval if calculations involve a single row at a time. Please, provide sample data and how you would like it to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldname)
SELECT CStr(table.feildname1) & CStr(table.feildname2) & CStr([feildname2]-[fieldname1])
FROM table;
```

But as @Tarik said, it is not recommended to store all fields in one column, unless it is some temp table or just for view.